# Getting many paid apps to colleague's personal iPad easily without manually installing them through the App Store?

Tags: ipad, privacy

I have about 20 apps that are are all paid apps, and I want my team-member to have them. He wants to use his own iPad, but we are tired to individually get apps from App Store. Is there some easy way like restoring from backup or something like that when I only want about 20 apps to the iPad? Suppose I need to do this for 10 people, is there any easy way that I say `'go to this site with your iPad and then you will get the apps and configured desktop for your work'`?

If there is no easy way, the guy needs to use two iPads. We are wanting to avoid this situation and not wanting `"to force people to new devices"` but we want to make sure that everyone has the best apps before any work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to purchase and distribute a set of apps to many users, [Apple's Volume Purchase Program](http://www.apple.com/business/vpp/) is probably what you want. Purchasing is done centrally, and then you can push out the apps via the [Apple Configurator](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apple-configurator/id434433123), or a third party management system.

Comment: ...what about if I have in-house-developed apps or apps not yet ready for publication? Or apps that are for sale but you are the developer, is the easiest way then promo-codes or other way?

Comment: To do in-house app distribution, you can use [Ad Hoc distribution](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/distribute.html) for up to 100 devices, or be enrolled in the [iOS Developer Enterprise Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/) for wider in-house distribution.